# replace column in data frame with elements from another column - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['g1','g1','g1','g2','g2','g2'], 'c2':['x','y','z','x','y','z'], 'v':[72,44,13,53,97,32]})
```

Is there a way to transform `df` in a way that `v` is replaced by the values `g1` and `g2` from column `c1`?

This is the output I'm trying to achieve:

```
    c2   g1   g2
0   x    72   53
1   y    44   97
2   z    13   32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) for that:

```
In [58]: df.pivot_table(index='c2', columns='c1', values='v').reset_index()
Out[58]:
c1 c2  g1  g2
0   x  72  53
1   y  44  97
2   z  13  32
```

Comment: That's great! It works perfectly! Thank you very much for your help!